# Django 1.5 (MEDIA_ROOT, TEMPLATE_DIRS)

Tags: python, django, web

I'm new to Django (1.5) and I'm having a hard time to relative configuration  of the media folder in MEDIA_ROOT. 
I can't charge the files .css, .js, .jpg in my project. I receive the following msg in the shell:

[06/Oct/2013 19:12:01] "GET /media/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4140

this is tree of the project:

- _3Ms

  - _3Ms
  - apps
  - media

    - css
    - js
    - images
  - template

this is my configuration

**setting.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = '_3Ms.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = '_3Ms.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates',
)
```

**home.html**

```
{% block css %}<link href="/media/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">{% endblock %}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You typically use `STATIC_URL` for your static assets like CSS and Javascript. Media is used for admin or user uploaded files.

So fill out your [`STATICFILES_DIR`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-dirs) and use `STATIC_URL` in your templates.

Settings:

```
import os.path

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], '..'))

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/path/to/your/static/assets',
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '..', 'static')),
]
```

Template:

```
{% block css %}<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">{% endblock %}
```

I'm assuming your are using the Django devserver.

Comment: Thanks for help me. I'm using django server, but in a future, it will entry in produccion, for this I want a relative MEDIA_ROOT. Your solution it's Ok but I need relative MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: Again, you don't want MEDIA_ROOT for static files like CSS and Javascript.

Comment: Explain what you mean by needing a relative path. I modified my example to show a more flexible way to name the paths.

Comment: Hi Brian, yes I need a relative path. I have tried the last solution, but it does't work. I have seen that the media folder  declares itself in MEDIA_ROOT. can you give me a solution to MEDIA_ROOT? thanks for help me

Comment: I think you should review the docs on static files and media files. Both MEDIA_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS require absolute paths. And again, you really don't want to serve your CSS and javascript out of your MEDIA_ROOT directory.

Comment: Are you also doing this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.urls.staticfiles_urlpatterns